# Using the private "lowercase" functions from a Go package

Tags: go, package

I'm trying so use the following function in my `main` package:

**[html.go](https://github.com/russross/blackfriday/blob/77efab57b2f74dd3f9051c79752b2e8995c8b789/html.go)** (from [blackfriday](https://github.com/russross/blackfriday)):

```
func doubleSpace(out *bytes.Buffer) {
    if out.Len() > 0 {
        out.WriteByte('\n')
    }
}
```

**main.go:**

```
func (options *renderer) Paragraph(out *bytes.Buffer, text func() bool) {
    marker := out.Len()
    doubleSpace(out)

    out.WriteString("<p class='custom'>")
    if !text() {
        out.Truncate(marker)
        return
    }
    out.WriteString("</p>\n")
}
```

I tried doing `blackfriday.doubleSpace` and `blackfriday.DoubleSpace` but in the three cases I get `undefined`.

What's the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. That is a deliberate decision by the authors of blackfriday. Your only option is to define your own function which does the same thing. It's just like accessing a private member in a language like Java.

See the spec here:
https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers